# YUV conversion getting only red color

Tags: yuv

I want to get the planes from a YUV image but the image that is being rendered is red, I thought that is was a problem with the UV planes order but switching UV I get a blue image (I can see the image, but it is blue or red color, depends on the UV order).

I don't know what is happening... Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are rendering a YUV image via a RGB viewer.

To pass from YUV to RGB, you just need to convert it via some coefficients.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV

```
R = Y + 1,13983⋅V
G = Y − 0,39465⋅U − 0,58060⋅V
B = Y + 2,03211⋅U
```

Comment: I think the first line is the real problem. If you view the first channel of any image in an RGB viewer, whether it's YUV, L*a*b*, or whatever, it's going to be displayed as red.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the diagram on the wikipage [YCbCr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr) it looks like you're missing the Cb (U) channel. Maybe you haven't found the right offset. How is the image subsampled?

Answer (score 0):

did you set the texture parameters for your y and uv texture? may be this is the reason.

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureY);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureUV);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```